# Irreducibilty of polynomial $x^9-6x^6+282x^3-8$ over $\mathbb {Q} $

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

While trying to deal with the final parts of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4213855/72031) I found that one needs to establish $$a=\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt{11}}\notin\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{11},\sqrt[3]{10})=F$$ Since both $a, F$ are of degree $6$ over $\mathbb {Q} $  the tower theorem does not help much.

Then I reasoned via contradiction. If $a\in F$ then $b=\sqrt[3]{1-\sqrt{11}}=-\sqrt[3]{10}/a\in F$ and hence $c=a+b\in F$.

One can check that $$c^3=a^3+b^3+3abc=2-3\sqrt[3]{10}c$$ or $$(c^3-2)^3=-270c^3$$ or $c$ is a root of $$f(x) =x^9-6x^6+282x^3-8$$ I checked using pari/gp that the polynomial $f(x) $ is irreducible over $\mathbb {Q} $. Further it can be observed that $f(289)$ is prime (also checked via pari/gp) so that the polynomial $f(x) $ is irreducible by [Murty's criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2758003/72031).

This shows that $c$ is of degree $9$ over $ \mathbb {Q} $ and hence $c\notin F$.

It can be observed that $f(x) $ can not be handled by Eisenstein as $2$ is the only prime which divides all non-leading coefficients and $4\mid 8$. I also checked the reducibility mod $3$ and the polynomial is reducible mod 3. So even that approach does not work. I don't know if using reducibility modulo other primes would help.

Is there is any other simpler way to prove the irreducibilty of $f(x) $ using hand computation?

**Update**: We have $$f(2x)=8(64x^9-48x^6+282x^3-1)=8g(x)$$ and it is somewhat easier to apply Murty's criterion on $g(x) $ with $g(8)=8577496063$ being prime. But I still find this unsuitable for hand calculation.

Comment: The Galois group of the polynomials is $S_3\times S_3$ which does not contain elements of order 9. Thus the polynomial will be reducible modulo every prime.

Comment: @ahulpke: is there general theorem like that which allows one to conclude that a polynomial will be reducible mod every prime?

Comment: I don't get the reason for downvotes. I am seeing a trend that most of my field theory questions are being downvoted. It would be a lot better if any feedback regarding improvement of the question is given.

Comment: (+1) I didn't know about Murty's criterion until now but it appears to be quite concealed in literature.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire: I came to know about it from mathse. It is a generalization of Cohen's criterion.

Comment: ParamanandSingh Initially I suspected that this can be quickly settled with tools from algebraic number theory. That may still be the case, but I could not see it right away. In the ring $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{11}]$ the principal ideal $I=(1+\sqrt{11})$ is the product $\mathfrak{p}_2\mathfrak{p}_5$ where $\mathfrak{p}_2=(2,1+\sqrt{11})$ is the sole prime above $2$, and $\mathfrak{p}_5=(4-\sqrt{11})$ is one of the ideals above the rational prime $5$. However, both $\mathfrak{p}_2$ and $\mathfrak{p}_5$ are totally ramified in the extension $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{11},\root3\of{10})/\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{11})$.

Comment: (cont'd) Meaning that in the ring of integers of the bigger field the ideal $(1+\sqrt{11})$ actually is a third power. This does not imply that the cube root would exist, but it does make the question more delicate. I have the impression that you would prefer a solution that does not need the machinery of ANT, but I suspect that it may be necessary. Therefore I added the tag. Of course, it is your call to remove it should you prefer it that way. My goal was to attract the people with the required expertise here. Hopefully they can rewrite an eventual answer in a more elementary language.

Comment: Hmm. Now I suspect that as $\mathfrak{p}_2$ is not principal, $(1+\sqrt{11})$ cannot be the cube of a *principal* ideal either. That would settle the question, but I need to sort out  a number of things in my head :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: although I don't know much of ANT, I would prefer the tag to stay.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : It appears you have figured out that the more interesting question here is about $a\notin F$ rather than the irreducibilty thing. Even I don't like my approach which requires a verification of irreducibilty of a ninth degree polynomial. There should be a more natural approach which is similar to proving $\sqrt[3]{3}\notin\mathbb {Q} (\sqrt[3]{2}) $ which is [handled here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2431221/72031).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, the general theory is a theorem by Frobenius whose more general form is Chebotarev's density theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebotarev%27s_density_theorem

Comment: It's unlikely that you can prove this by hand, since it's degree 9 - much harder than proving a 9 digit number is prime.

Comment: Using Dedekind's theorem it is possible to prove that the splitting field of the minimal polynomial of $a$ has degree at least $36$, hence exactly $36$, settling the original question. I posted the argument there. But it is also computer aided, and does not advance the cause much at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is the most elementary solution that I have.

Let us first consider the problem of factoring $f(x)$ modulo $7$. In the field $\Bbb{F}_7$ we have $11=4$, so $\sqrt{11}=2$. This gives us the counterparts
$\tilde{a}=\root3\of{1+\sqrt{11}}=\root3\of{3}$,
$\tilde{b}=-\root3\of{10}/a=-\root3\of{3}/a=-1$ and hence $\tilde{c}=\tilde{a}+\tilde{b}=\root3\of3-1$. It is easy to check that $3$ is not a cubic residue modulo $7$, so the minimal polynomial of $\tilde{c}$ over $\Bbb{F}_7$ is thus
$$h(x)=(x+1)^3-3=x^3+3x^2+3x-2\in\Bbb{F}_7[x].$$
Paramanand Singh's calculations survive to the extent that we can conclude that $h(x)$ must be a factor of $f(x)$ modulo $7$.

Another ingredient is that $f(x)=x^9-6x^3+282x^3-8$ has the property $f(\omega x)=f(x)$ for any cubic root of unity $\omega$. This follows from the fact that all the terms of $f(x)$ have degrees divisible by three. In $\Bbb{F}_7$ we have the primitive third roots of unity: $\mu_3=\{1,2,4\}$. Therefore $h(2x)=x^3+5x^2+6x-2$ and $h(4x)=x^3+6x^2+5x-2$ must also be factors of $f(x)$ in $\Bbb{F}_7[x]$. Indeed, it is easy to verify that over $\Bbb{F}_7$ the factorization of $f(x)$ into irreducibles is
$$f(x)=h(x)h(2x)h(4x).$$

This implies that any factorization of $f(x)$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ can only have factors of degrees $3$ or $6$, so it suffices to exclude the possibility of a cubic factor. We make the observation that the same applies over the field $\Bbb{Q}(\omega)$, $\omega=(-1+i\sqrt3)/2$. This is because the ring $E=\Bbb{Z}[\omega]$ of Eisensteinian integers is known to be a Euclidean domain (w.r.t. the complex norm) and also because the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}=\langle 2+i\sqrt3\rangle$ has index seven in $E$. The argument is familiar. By Gauss's lemma a polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}(\omega)$ iff it is irreducible over $E$, and then reduction modulo $\mathfrak{p}$ works the same way as reduction modulo $7$ does over $\Bbb{Z}$. This is because $E/\mathfrak{p}\simeq\Bbb{F}_7$.

Assume that $g(x)=x^3+Ax^2+Bx+C\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$ is a cubic factor of $f(x)$. By the above observations then $g(\omega x)$ and $g(\omega^2x)$ are also factors of $f(x)$, but possibly they reside in $E[x]$. Should we have $g(x)=g(\omega x)$ (when also $g(x)=g(\omega^2x)$ by complex conjugation), then $g(x)=x^3+C$. But this is impossible because $f(x)=F(x^3)$ with $F(x)=x^3-6x^2+282x-8$. The rational root test then shows that $F(x)$ is has no rational zeros, so $F(-C)\neq0$.

So we can conclude that $g(x)$, $g(\omega x)$ and $g(\omega^2x)$ are all distinct and irreducible over $E$. We are left with the possibility that
$$f(x)=g(x)g(\omega x)g(\omega^2x).$$
Expanding everything gives
$$g(x)g(\omega x)g(\omega^2x)=x^9+(A^3-3AB+3C)x^6+(B^3-3ABC+3C^2)x^3+C^3.$$
A comparison of the constant terms immediately reveals $C=-2$. Plugging that into the $x^6$-term gives the equation $A^3-3AB=0$. So either $A=0$ or $A^2=3B$.

- If $A=0$ a comparison of $x^3$ terms yields $B^3=270$ which is
  impossible given that $B$ is an integer.
- If $A^2=3B$ and $B^3+3AB=270$, then
  $$A^6+27A^3=27(B^3+3AB)=7290.$$ But it is easy to check that this has no integer solutions.

The irreducibility of $f(x)$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ follows from this.

Comment: +1. I was  hoping that somehow in this particular case one could deduce the irreducibilty of $f(x) $ using the irreducibilty of the cubic $f(x^{1/3})$. While this is not always guaranteed, for this case your analysis shows that this works. I will need some time to assimilate all the details though.

Comment: The basic idea is similar to the one I used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3722289/11619) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3921481/11619). On the earlier occasions only even degree terms were present, and I used the second primitive root of unity. This time I had to use the third roots of unity. That has the unfortunate consequence of needing to mention the Eisensteinians along the way. I guess further simplification may be possible. Also the presentation can be polished. I need to work on those.

Comment: It was anything but obvious to look at this modulo seven. I guess I might as well confess that I first found the factorization with Mathematica. But I did spot the $g(x)$, $g(\omega x)$, $g(\omega^2x)$ pattern among the factors because I was looking for it!

Comment: Will this argument work? If $p(x) $ is a factor of $f(x) $ then $p(x), p(wx), p(w^2x)$ will be factors of $f(x) $ over $E[x] $. If $p(x) $ is of degree 1, we get a factor. $p(x) p(wx) p(w^2x)\in\mathbb {Q} [x] $ of degree $3$. If $p(x)$ is of degree $2$ then $f(x) /(p(x) p(wx) p(w^2x)$ is a factor of degree $3$. And we can't have degree of $p(x) $ greater than $3$. It follows that if the polynomial is reducible over $\mathbb {Q} [x] $ it must have a cubic polynomial as a factor. This avoids dealing with factorization modulo primes.

Comment: Based on my previous comment, I think we can use this technique whenever we need to deal with polynomials in $x^3$ with rational coefficients.

Comment: Something like that should work @ParamanandSingh. We have a cyclic group of order three acting on the factors. There is always the possibility that $p(x)=p(\omega x)$, that is, a fixed point of the action. That possibility leads to a factorization of $f(x^{1/3})$. I was worried about the possibility of those factors not remaining irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}(\omega)$. Particularly because I wanted to call upon the uniqueness of factorization. That is actually not necessary, but I need to think about this a bit more.

Comment: The case $p(x) =p(\omega x) $ will not arise if the degree of $p(x) $ is not divisible by $3$ because the leading coefficients will differ. So I think the argument should work fine.

Answer (score 5):

The $2$-adic [Newton polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polygon) for $f(x) = x^9-6x^6+282x^3-8$ immediately tells us that if $f(x)$ is reducible, its factorization must look like
$$f(x) = (x^6 + \ldots \pm 2)(x^3 + \ldots \mp4).$$
In particular, $f(x)$ must have three roots whose product is $\pm4$. Using any root estimation technique (see below), we find that $f(x)$ has six roots satisfying $2 < |x| < 3$ and three roots satisfying $1/4 < |x| < 1/3$. But no combination of three values from those ranges has product with absolute value $4$, so $f(x)$ is irreducible.

---

To estimate the roots of $f(x)$, we can use an (unfortunately) obscure technique which is essentially a version of Newton polygons for $\mathbb{C}$ instead of $\mathbb{C_p}$:

For this problem, the upper convex hull of the points $(i, \log|a_i|)$ has vertices at $(0, \log 8)$, $(3, \log 282)$, and $(9, 0)$. As with $p$-adic Newton polygons, an estimation for the logarithm of the absolute value of the roots, $\log|x_i|$, is given by the negative slopes of the convex hull. In this case we have six roots with $\log|x_i| \approx -\dfrac{0-\log 282}{9-3} = \log \sqrt[6]{282}$ and three roots with $\log|x_i| \approx -\dfrac{\log 282 - \log 8}{3-0} = \log\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{8}{282}}$, which gives us the estimates above, noting that $2 < \sqrt[6]{282} < 3$ and $\dfrac{1}{4} < \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{8}{282}} < \dfrac{1}{3}$.

To formalize this into a proof, we would use [Rouché's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem) in the two annuli $2 < |x| < 3$ and $1/4 < |x| < 1/3$.

This method is essentially what is used in some implementations of the Aberth root-finding algorithm as a first approximation of the roots; see the paper [Numerical computation of polynomial zeros by means of Aberth's method](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225654837_Numerical_computation_of_polynomial_zeros_by_means_of_Aberth%27s_method) by Bini (1996). One word of caution: this technique is very accurate when the polynomial has roots that are well-separated, but gives inaccurate results when there are several roots that are close together on a log scale.

Comment: This is a very enlightening proof!

Comment: Seconding orangeskid's sentiment :-)

Comment: Nice approach. I will have to read some more details on Newton polygons, but the key idea of using the location of roots is really cool. +1 already given.

Answer (score 3):

The polynomial $P(x)$ factors $\!\!\!\mod \!\!13$ as $(x^3+6) ( x^6+ x^3 + 3) $  ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%5Bx%5E9-6x%5E6%2B282x%5E3-8%2C%20Modulus-%3E13%5D)).

Assume that $P(x)$  is reducible. We conclude that $P(x)$ is a product of two  polynomials $P_1(x)$, $P_2(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.  with $P_1(x)\equiv x^3 + 6 \!\!\!\mod \!\!13$, $P_2(x)\equiv x^6 + x^3 + 3 \!\!\!\mod\!\! 13$.

Now, $P(1) =269$, a prime number. We conclude $P_1(1)=\pm 1$, or $P_2(1)=\pm 1$.  But $P_1(1)\equiv  7 \!\!\!\mod \!\!13$, while $P_2(1)\equiv 5 \!\!\!\mod \!\!13$, contradiction.

..........................................................

$\bf{Added:}$ About the factorization $\mod 13$. Our polynomial is $P(x) = Q(x^3)$, with $Q(x)= x^3 - 6 x^2 + 282 x - 8$. Now $Q(x)$ has root $7$ $\mod 13$, so we have
$Q(x) = (x-7)(x^2 + x + 3)$, and so
$P(x) = (x^3 - 7)(x^6+x^3 + 3)$. Now $x^3-7$ has no root $\mod 13$, because $7^{\frac{12}{3}}= 7^4 \not \equiv 1 \mod 13$.  Also, $x^2 + x + 3 = x^2 + 2 \cdot 7 x + 7^2 + 3 - 7^2= (x+7)^2 - 7$, and $7$ is not a quadratic residue $\mod 13$, so $x^2 + x + 3$ is irreducible.

Based on Jyrki's idea: Note that since $13\equiv 1 \mod 3$, there exists $\omega \in \mathbb{F}_{13}$, such that $\omega^3 = 1$, and $\omega\ne 1$ ( a primitive root of $1).  \mod 13$). Now, consider the action of the group of roots of $1$ on monic polynomials $f(x) \mapsto \frac{1}{\omega^{\deg f}} f(\omega x)$. The polynomials in $x^3$ are invariated by the action ( the fixed points are $x^m \cdot $ pol in $x^3$). Therefore, the a polynomial in $x^3$, its irreducible factors will be either polynomials in $x^3$, or group in orbits of size $3$ under this action. Now, if the polynomial $x^6 + x^3 + 3$ were reducible, it would equal $R(x) R(\omega x) R(\omega^2 x)$, where $R$ is a polynomial of degree $2$. But that would imply that the free term $3$ is a cube. However, we have $3^{\frac{12}{3}} = 3^4 =3 \mod 13$. Therefore, $x^6 + x^3 + 3$ is irreducible $\mod 13$.

Comment: Very well spotted! It never ceases to amaze me in how many ways we can skin these cats.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: Thank you!   Still puzzled why $P$ seems to have a factor of degree $3$  mod every $p$ I tried.

Comment: That is [Dedekind and Frobenius/Chebotarev](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/160855/11619) in action. The Galois group has no elements of order nine, so the polynomial will factor modulo each and every prime. It does not have irreducible factors of degree three modulo 17 (for example): 3 linear $\times$ 3 quadratics. All in line of the Galois group having elements of order two. All the elements of the Galois group have orders $6,3,2$ or $1$, but I haven't even tried to identify it. The group has order $36$, and its Sylow $3$-subgroup must be elementary abelian, but the rest is unclear to me.

Comment: Oh! User ahulpke had figured out that the Galois group is $S_3\times S_3$. That has elements of all observed orders, and fits the observed facts. I vaguely recall having satisfied myself of that fact at some point, too. But the I got stuck into the "program" of using the third roots of unity. I really should rethink my answer, and rewrite it in a clean way. May be later :-)

Comment: +1 and this is very smart. It does need a bit of work (or CAS) to factor modulo primes, but overall the argument is easy to understand.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: in case you intend to update your answer, please keep original approach also and may be add something more. Your approach can be used in many cases when we have a polynomial in $x^3$.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: Thank you, very useful info, will have to chew on it. About the Galois group being $S_3 \times S_3$, I can think of one transitive action on $9$ objects, more thinking required.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh: Thank you! About your original problem, there is a fairly simple way to show that radicals are linearly independent,  using traces ( in general, the trace of any radical is $0$, so we can play with that).

Comment: @orangeskid: I have seen a few answers related to algebraic number theory which use trace in a simple and elegant manner. It would be nice if you can post an answer (to the original linked question) based on traces.

Comment: I found your answer based on traces: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2431293/72031 I think that should work fine for the original problem.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh: The basic field should be $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11})$ ( in general, a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$). Then real radicals that are incomparable are also linearly independent over the field. ... there is another answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158722/linear-independence-of-nth-roots-over-mathbbq/2432555#2432555       turns out it's a result of Siegel... short paper in German